# Is there a way to add data to DrawingVisual

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing

I have a custom drawn control (overrides `FrameworkElement`) with several `DrawingVisual` objects. I'm keeping a list of visuals and overriding `GetVisualChild` and `VisualChildrenCount`. Performance is important, so most of them use `BitmapCache`.

One of visuals is going to be updated with new data every 50 ms. It draws a path which a machine takes in real world, so every 50 ms. there's a new line to draw, keeping old lines still there.

What would be the best way to draw this with good performance, so without redrawing existing machine path, but just adding another line? It seems once you draw something in the visual using `RenderOpen` you can't modify it. I tried `visual.Drawing.Append()` but it seems it doesn't draw anything.

Is there a way to add new data to `DrawingVisual`? If not, what to use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps create a RenderTargetBitmap that you draw to instead, then when the OnRender call is made do a Context.DrawImage

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace WpfApplication13
{
    public class PanelTest : FrameworkElement
    {
        public RenderTargetBitmap _renderTargetBitmap = null;
        public System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer _Timer = null;
        public int _iYLoc = 0;
        private Pen _pen = null;

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
            {
                drawingContext.DrawImage(_renderTargetBitmap, new Rect(0, 0, 250, 250));
            }


            base.OnRender(drawingContext);
        }

        public PanelTest() :base()
        {
            _renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(250, 250, 96, 96, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            _pen = new Pen(Brushes.Red, 1);
            _Timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
            _Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 50);
            _Timer.Tick += _Timer_Tick;
            if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
            {
                _Timer.Start();
            }
        }

        private void _Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DrawingVisual vis = new DrawingVisual();
            DrawingContext con = vis.RenderOpen();
            con.DrawLine(_pen, new Point(0, _iYLoc), new Point(250, _iYLoc));
            _iYLoc++;

            con.Close();

            _renderTargetBitmap.Render(vis);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your example works great. I ported it to my application and it also works perfect, however I needed to add `InvalidateVisual` after `_renderTargetBitmap.Render(vis)`. Otherwise nothing was drawn. Maybe this is because I'm using custom list of visuals. But still I can't understand one thing - how does anything in WPF indrastructure know it should render the control after your _Timer_Tick?

Comment: Ok I got it (I think). I was creating a bitmap somewhen when the first machine movement came, and not in the constructor like you - and this is where I have to call `InvalidateVisual` just one time, to force `OnRender` draw this bitmap. In your case it was drawn at initial drawing. And then it seems after the bitmap is drawn (added to the visual), further modifying the bitmap automatically redraws everything - looks magic to me but it works.

Comment: I think you can use VisualBrush.